# How to short a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL like:

```
www.zzz.com/ExternalDocuments/ExternalDocumentUpload.aspx?hjgbasdjfjsggfsdf
```

I want to provide something short for `ExternalDocuments/ExternalDocumentUpload.aspx`. I don't want to shorten the whole url.

Comment: What did you try? How did it not work as you expected?

Comment: Its not that difficult to short an URL or part of an URL and append some different string to the original URL part in place of an long URL as in your case, but your web server should know that this URL needs to be redirected to the original one. Have you thought of that first?
There are many algorithms you can apply here. The simplest would be to just take random chars from that mini URL and perhaps 5 chars and make it a new 1. But that will not be a long standing algorithm for u.

Comment: Actually there is already one url working for all the pages but this url is seperate for which user need not to login. I have that code but not able to understand where shall i look to find this out. Maybe masterpage or default login page?

Comment: You could simply use a different file name.  You don't explain the entirety of what you want to accomplish (redirect? simply visible externally as the new URL, without redirect?), or what context you want to accomplish it in (users typing it in?  Pasting on blogs?).  You have some serious ambiguity (did you want to get rid of the query string?), and you don't explain whether you want it for a single URL, or for every page on your site.  Voting to close because the question is vague, unless a lot more details are provided.

Comment: Also, if the query string is used by your code then there will be no clean way to remove it from your URL, nor should you try.  It is already in a good spot, and moving it elsewhere in the HTTP request would probably just complicate your code, with no benefit to anyone.

Comment: ExternalDocuments/ExternalDocumentUpload ... it could be just ExternalDocuments/Upload, that is an external document is implicit by its folder.

Comment: I have to do it only for this page. My client is saying the url is too long, it would be good if i can change the part of ExternalDocuments/ExternalDocumentUpload.aspx to ExtDoc/ExtDoc.aspx. The query string is used by the page to parse the Id which i am encapsulating. Based on the id i am showing the data.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want isn't "shortening" -- where a service like e.g. `bit.ly` is used to shorten the entire URL for use in Twitter or suchlike -- but "URL rewriting".

This takes a "friendly" path provided by the user -- to the right of the "/" -- and turns it into the URL you need for ASP.NET to find the page.

There's a few different ways to do this depending on precisely which flavour of ASP.NET and IIS you're using. ScottGu has a good roundup here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

and for IIS7 I've used the one here:

http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 1):

You can set up url rewriting in global.asax file, on Application_BeginRequest event, that would run on every request, checking requested url and, if needed, redirecting it to desired url. You can make the checking like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.RawUrl== "/someShorturl/page.aspx")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/ExternalDocuments/ExternalDocumentUpload.aspx?hjgbasdjfjsggfsdf");
    }
}
```

So, if user goes to "www.zzz.com/someShorturl/page.aspx", he will get "www.zzz.com/ExternalDocuments/ExternalDocumentUpload.aspx?hjgbasdjfjsggfsdf" page, although url in the browser won't change.

If you'd like to change shortened url into long original url, you can call Response.Redirect instead the RewritePath method.

This example is for one speciffic url, but you can create more complex logic, of course.